# Sort a worksheet using a column of dates as the primary key

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet that contains multiple columns; among these columns I have one that contains dates. I want to sort the column that contains the dates and automatically sort the sheet.

Comment: Why are dates different from sorting any other type of number?

Comment: I have a column contains the date (dd / mm / YYYY)...but I want to apply a function to a table (sheet). This table needs to be sorted by the date in column A that contains dates. So if the sheet is not sorted by increasing date I will have different results.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a date can be found (and identified with VBA's [IsDate function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00wf8zk9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) in the second row between column A and the last used column of A1's current region then this should locate the first column with dates and sort in an ascending manner.

```
Sub sort_by_first_date()
    Dim iDateCol As Date
    With ActiveSheet
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            For iDateCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                If IsDate(.Cells(2, iDateCol)) Then Exit For
            Next iDateCol
            If iDateCol <= .Columns.Count Then  'make sure a column with dates was found
                .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(iDateCol), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
            End If
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

If you need to look further down that the second row you will need to adjust the conditional statement within the For...Next.

Comment: if I sort my sheet manually my function that does a search against the criterion is always going to take that sort l?

Comment: @memed - I'm unclear on your question. If you sort it manually you should already know which column contains the dates you want to sort on.